# Need jQuery localstorage to retain checkbox

Tags: jquery, checkbox, radio-button, local-storage

I know I might not be asking for this, so, sorry.

Any way, I need a jQuery function to retain checkboxes and radio button on page reload/refresh. I have one that works using cookies, but my requirements are quite high(hundreds of checkboxes and radio buttons)

I need a link to some demo or example that uses localstorage (function should be based solely on input IDs.

Thanks in advance.

P.S. I'm not a front end developer...

Comment: If you could figure out how to do it with cookies, local storage is even easier.

Comment: How I missed it? I don't know. Any way thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a "jquery function", juste use `Window.localStorage` or `Window.sessionStorage` directly.
It's very simple to use, but note that it only supports strings, not any other types.

Some tutorial [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API).

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is exactly what I needed

Comment: @user3134422 you're welcome, could you please accept the answer then ...?

Comment: If you need to save other types, you can convert them to strings with `JSON.stringify()`.